# mapping list from JPA Query.getResultList() to a customized TO

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have a table fruit with four columns id, name, color, shape.

entries in the table would be:

```
1, apple, red, round
2, banana, yellow, long
3, tomato, red, round
4, orange, orange, round
```

Now I made an entity class Fruit mapped to above table.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="fruit")
public class Fruit implements Serializable {

@Id
@Column(name="ID")
String id;

@Column(name="NAME")
String name;

@Column(name="COLOR")
String color;

@Column(name="SHAPE")
String shape;

//getters/setters goes here
}
```

In my DAO class, the code is:

```
String myQuery = "Select f.shape, f.name from Fruit f where f.shape = :shape";
Query query = this.em.createQuery(myQuery);
query.setParameter("shape", "round");
```

As obvious, running above query will return 3 rows.

I have a simple TO class FruitSearchTO

```
class FruitSearchTO
{
  String shape;
  String name;

  //getters/setters here
}
```

This TO complies with the rows returned by my query.

But in my DAO running something like:

```
List<FruitSearchTO> fruitList = new ArrayList<FruitSearchTO>();  
fruitList = query.getResultList();
```

is throwing exception java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; incompatible with FruitSearchTO]

Where am I going wrong and what is the solution to this ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The HQL you're using will return a `List<Object[]>`, each element of the `List` being an array with `shape` in position 0 and `name` in position 1.

You can make the HQL return a `List<FruitSearchTO>` using an [`AliasToBeanResultTransformer`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/transform/Transformers.html#aliasToBean%28java.lang.Class%29):

```
List fruitList = s.createQuery(
  "select f.shape as shape, f.name as name from Fruit f where f.shape = :shape;")
  .setParameter("shape", paramShape)
  .setResultTransformer( Transformers.aliasToBean(FruitSearchTO.class))
  .list();
FruitSearchTOdto = (FruitSearchTO) fruitList .get(0);
```

Alternatively, if `FruitSearchTO` has an appropriate constructor:, you can also achieve this with `select new FruitSearchTO(f.shape, f.name)`.

Take a look at the Hibernate Reference chapter on HQL, particularly [15.6 The `select` clause](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-select) chapter.

Comment: Thanks Xavi.. let me try out this and get back to you!!

Comment: Can you please paste your earlier answer. I am using older version of Hibernate and it does not have ResultTransformer method.

Comment: got it!! thanks.. I could not verify the above answer due to version issues. however, the iterator version did work!!

Comment: @JamesDW Thank you for your edit, it indeed seems that the DTO is not required to be included in the mappings.

Answer (score 4):

In JPQL you have a `NEW` operator which allows you to create an instance of the object on-the-fly which doesn't have to be an entity itself (just like in your case - a DTO is not an Entity).

If you don't want to go with vendor-specific solution you might use the `NEW` operator or just iterate over resulting Object[] and create your DTO by yourself.

These might be a interesting materials for you: [How can I avoid the creation of superfluous entities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7927604/how-can-i-avoid-the-creation-of-superfluous-entities/7927778#comment9684940_7927778), and [a bit about the NEW operator](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/select#Result_Classes_Constructor_Expressions_).