# Casting types in Java 8 streams

Tags: java, lambda, casting, java-8

To gain some experience with Java's new streams, I've been developing a framework for handling playing cards. Here's the first version of my code for creating a `Map` containing the number of cards of each suit in a hand (`Suit` is an `enum`):

```
Map<Suit, Long> countBySuit = contents.stream() // contents is ArrayList<Card>  
        .collect( Collectors.groupingBy( Card::getSuit, Collectors.counting() ));
```

This worked great and I was happy. Then I refactored, creating separate Card subclasses for "Suit Cards" and Jokers. So the `getSuit()` method was moved from the `Card` class to its subclass `SuitCard`, since Jokers don't have a suit. New code:

```
Map<Suit, Long> countBySuit = contents.stream() // contents is ArrayList<Card>  
        .filter( card -> card instanceof SuitCard ) // reject Jokers
        .collect( Collectors.groupingBy( SuitCard::getSuit, Collectors.counting() ) );
```

Notice the clever insertion of a filter to make sure that the card being considered is in fact a Suit Card and not a Joker. But it doesn't work! Apparently the `collect` line doesn't realize that the object it's being passed is GUARANTEED to be a `SuitCard`.

After puzzling over this for a good while, in desperation I tried inserting a `map` function call, and amazingly it worked!

```
Map<Suit, Long> countBySuit = contents.stream() // contents is ArrayList<Card>  
        .filter( card -> card instanceof SuitCard ) // reject Jokers
        .map( card -> (SuitCard)card ) // worked to get rid of error message on next line
        .collect( Collectors.groupingBy( SuitCard::getSuit, Collectors.counting() ) );
```

I had no idea that casting a type was considered an executable statement. Why does this work? And why does the compiler make it necessary?

Comment: You're changing a `Stream<Card>` to a `Stream<SuitCard>`, so it compiles fine when executing a `SuitCard` method on the `SuitCard` elements. Think if you did it manually, you'd still have `Card` objects and have to cast them in your loop

Comment: It basically boils down to: why does the compiler want you to cast after an `instanceof` call, since there's no way it could fail if you assign the variable to the type you just checked it was an instance of. There are probably good reasons for this, like, would it really make the code clearer and shorter? Is it worth the effort of wiring the compiler to do this?

Comment: If the data to stream comes from hibernate, this answer might be useful:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39604095/objects-from-hibernate-wont-cast

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Remember that a `filter` operation will not change the compile-time type of the `Stream`'s elements.  Yes, logically we see that everything that makes it past this point will be a `SuitCard`, all that the `filter` sees is a `Predicate`.  If that predicate changes later, then that could lead to other compile-time issues.

If you want to change it to a `Stream<SuitCard>`, you'd need to add a mapper that does a cast for you:

```
Map<Suit, Long> countBySuit = contents.stream() // Stream<Card>
    .filter( card -> card instanceof SuitCard ) // still Stream<Card>, as filter does not change the type
    .map( SuitCard.class::cast ) // now a Stream<SuitCard>
    .collect( Collectors.groupingBy( SuitCard::getSuit, Collectors.counting() ) );
```

I refer you to the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) for the full details.

Comment: For instanceof, I also like the method reference way better: `.filter(SuitCard.class::isInstance)`

Comment: True, but given that `instanceof` was a key part of the question, it was inappropriate to change it on this particular occasion.

Comment: `SuitCard.class::cast` is nice, but unfortunately less efficient than `c -> (SuitCard) c` because `Class.cast` performs a redundant `isInstance` check.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Are you sure?  Because a normal cast operation does an instance check as well (how would a `ClassCastException` be thrown otherwise?).

Comment: @JoeC Quite sure, just inspect the (OpenJDK) implementation. And yes, the cast internally *also* performs such a check (or rather, the JRE does). But `Class<T>.cast` performs an *additional*, redundant check.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Ah, I gotcha.

Answer (score 16):

Well, `map()` allows transforming a `Stream<Foo>` into a `Stream<Bar>` using a function that takes a `Foo` as argument and returns a `Bar`. And

```
card -> (SuitCard) card
```

is such a function: it takes a Card as argument and returns a SuitCard.

You could write it that way if you wanted to, maybe that makes it clearer to you:

```
new Function<Card, SuitCard>() {
    @Override
    public SuitCard apply(Card card) {
        SuitCard suitCard = (SuitCard) card;
        return suitCard;
    }
}
```

The compiler makes that necessary because filter() transforms a `Stream<Card>` into a `Stream<Card>`. So you can't apply a function only accepting SuitCard to the elements of that stream, which could contain any kind of Card: the compiler doesn't care about what your filter does. It only cares about what type it returns.

Comment: Excellent explanation @JB . Actually, it's more understandable to me if I envision the lambda as being written         `card -> {return (SuitCard)card;}`

Answer (score 4):

Actually the problem is that you have a `Stream<Card>` type, even though after filtering you are pretty sure that the stream contains nothing but `SuitCard` objects. You know that, but compiler does not. If you don't want to add an executable code into your stream, you can do instead an unchecked cast to `Stream<SuitCard>`:

```
Map<Suit, Long> countBySuit = ((Stream<SuitCard>)contents.stream()
    .filter( card -> card instanceof SuitCard ))
    .collect( Collectors.groupingBy( SuitCard::getSuit, Collectors.counting() ) );
```

This way casting will not add any instructions to compiled bytecode. Unfortunately this looks quite ugly and produces a compiler warning. In my [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex) library I hid this ugliness inside library method [`select()`](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex/blob/5bfd237714f775a79e69b33b4d5b030ea322ee54/src/main/java/one/util/streamex/StreamEx.java#L119), so using StreamEx you can write

```
Map<Suit, Long> countBySuit = StreamEx.of(contents)
    .select( SuitCard.class )
    .collect( Collectors.groupingBy( SuitCard::getSuit, Collectors.counting() ) );
```

Or even shorter:

```
Map<Suit, Long> countBySuit = StreamEx.of(contents)
    .select( SuitCard.class )
    .groupingBy( SuitCard::getSuit, Collectors.counting() );
```

If you don't like using third-party libraries, your solution involving additional `map` step looks ok. Even though it adds some overhead, usually it's not very significant.

Comment: The method reference `SuitCard::getSuit` will bear a type cast to `SuitCard` in any case, which is the reason why the unchecked cast of the stream to `Stream<SuitCard>` does work. So when replacing `SuitCard::getSuit`  with `x -> ((SuitCard)x).getSuit()`, you‘re not sacrificing anything…

Comment: @Tagir Valeev Thank you for the StreamEx library. You are the man!

Answer (score 2):

The type of contents is `Card`, so `contents.stream()` returns `Stream<Card>`. Filter does guarantee that each item in the resulting stream is a `SuitCard`, however, filter does not change the type of the stream. `card -> (SuitCard)card` is functionally equivalent to `card -> card`, but it's type is `Function<Card,Suitcard>`, so the `.map()` call returns a `Stream<SuitCard>`.