# How to Cast From Object to My Class in Java

Tags: java, object, casting

I'm Playing around with maps and i did this

```
Map<String, Map<String, Object>> maps = new HashMap<>();
User user = new User("name", "age");
Profile profile = new Profile(user, "ADMIN")
Map<String, User> userMap = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, Profile> profileMap = new HashMap<>();

userMap.put(user.getUserId(), user);
profileMap.put(profile.getProfileId(), profile);
maps.put("Profiles", profileMap);
maps.put("Users", usesrMap);
```

How can i get profile or user objects from this map?
for example i want to get a specific profile using id

```
public Profile getById(String id) { // i get error here unless i change return type to object
   return maps.get("Profiles").values().stream()
       .filter(p -> ((Profile)p).getProfileId().equals(id));
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Casting types in Java 8 streams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39840749/casting-types-in-java-8-streams)

Comment: `.filter(p -> ((Profile)p)` shouldn’t even compile.  But `.map(p -> ((Profile)p)` will.  Of course, you could just forego streams and use `return (Profile) maps.get("Profiles").get(id);`.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it by calling `.get()`. After you do:

```
profileMap.put(profile.getProfileId(), profile);
```

try:

```
profileMap.get(profile.getProfileId())
```

and it should yield you the profile you just added. So, if you have an id, you can get the profile from the map as long as it is to be found inside of it. If you do not know whether a value is to be found and you want to default the value to something, then you can also use `getOrDefault`.